# Github authentication failed

Tags: git, github

I have a problem I changed my email address for my Github account, and I kept the old one, but the new one as a primary.
I tried to push a code and I receive this error:

```
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed......
```

How can I solve this problem, please note that I'm using a mac.

Comment: I guess you may have to update your ssh keypairs? Or auth info in config file?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: You work with windows10?

Comment: Are you using a credential helper to cache the username and password for HTTPS urls? `git config credential.helper` prints the helper if any.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you are entering a Personal Access Token, not your GitHub account password. Take a look at this blog: https://medium.com/@ginnyfahs/github-error-authentication-failed-from-command-line-3a545bfd0ca8

Comment: This article pointed out that you have to use the "classic" PAT, not the fine-grained, newer type.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the *credentials* from yours github-account in *credential manager* (finding by searching "Credential Manager") and by execute the next command to your github-server (as example `git pull`) you will be asked to log into github, where you have to use the *new* email. After login, the credentials for your github-account are changed and saved again in the credential manager.